# ANdroid Application not connect to REST in Mobile data

Tags: android

I have created an application to the MDM server for a client, The application uses private API that implemented in load balancing server. I'm using retrofit to connect with the REST. The application running smoothly on private WIFI network of client.

It showing error as

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl take a look at this. 

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have dependancy **note** : retrofit_version add latest version of retrofit

```
  // retrofit
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version") {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3"
}
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit_version"
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$retrofit_version") {
    exclude module: "rxjava"
}
```

And in your code

```
  protected OkHttpClient initOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = Tls12OkHttpClientFactory.enableTls12OnPreLollipop(new OkHttpClient.Builder()); // TODO : Check This

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        // Adding logging interceptor
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);

        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new FakeInterceptor(mContext));
    }


    // add Timeouts
    okHttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    return okHttpClientBuilder.build();
}


public Retrofit initRetrofit() {
    if (mRetrofit == null) {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mServerBaseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ProtoConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        mRetrofit = builder
                .client(initOkHttpClient())
                .build();
    }
    return mRetrofit;
}
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: This code only adds TimeOuts. My application not working for Android P also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https to connect then remove s and use http only and check if it works